# Build real time chat using node.js, npmjs websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Here is an image of sample chat I am working on. You'll find some description there

[image]

I have `node.js` and `npm websocket` installed. The local server works fine, but I do have difficulties with chat functionality.  The only thing that works fine is message exchange (messages synchronized for all users). New user automatically created with unique random id if new browser tab was opened with the same HTML file. All issues are below:

- real-time user status update (every user can see other users status and name within the tab he's using
- there are links to other (empty) chats with same styling and functionality. Please, follow the image link to know what are they for
- before a user starts using chat he should signup through a simple form. The form should cover chat container, and after user press "Join chat" button this form should disappear. The input value should be stored and used in messages and user status (e.g. Gandalf: Run, you fools! Frodo: Noooooo! && Sam Dumbo)

---

Here is full code I have:

```js
/******BROWSER.JS*********************************/

const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
//var clients = {};
let name = document.getElementById('login').value;
var customers = [];


document.forms.publish.onsubmit = function() {
  let text = this.message.value;
  socket.send(text);
  return false;
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  let serverMessage = event.data;
  showMessage(serverMessage);
};

function showMessage(serverMessage) {

  const messageContainer = document.getElementById('subscribe');
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
  messageElement.setAttribute('id', 'message');
  messageElement.append(document.createTextNode(serverMessage));
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
}

// toSend = () => (showName(name));
//
// //     = function (event) {
// //     let serverMessage = event.data;
// //     showMessage(serverMessage);
// // };
//
// function showName(name) {
//
//     const nameContainer = document.getElementById('status');
//     const nameElement = document.createElement('div');
//
//     nameElement.append(document.createTextNode(name));
//     nameContainer.append(nameElement);
//
//     return name;
// }

// socket.onopen = function(data){
//     document.createElement('input');
//
//     data = 'online';
//     setStatus(data);
// };


// socket.onopen = function(){
//     let customers = [];
//     let name = document.getElementById('login').value;
//     customers.push(name);
//
//             for (let name of customers) {
//                 setStatus('online');
//             }
//
// };

function signUp(name) {
  name = document.getElementById('login').value;
  customers.push(name);

  for (let any in customers) {
    setStatus(`${name}`);
  }
}
//
function setStatus(value) {
  //value = 'online';
  const statusContainer = document.getElementById('status');
  const statusElement = document.createElement('span');
  statusElement.setAttribute('id', 'statusElem');
  statusElement.append(document.createTextNode(value));
  statusContainer.append(statusElement);
}
//
//
//
// let logBtn = document.getElementById('start');
// logBtn.addEventListener('click', signUp, false);


//
let loginBtn = document.getElementById('join');
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', signUp, false);

// socket.onclose = function(event){
//     event.data = 'offline';
//     setStatus(event.data);
// };
```

```js
/*******************SERVER.JS****************************/
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

var clients = {};

var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
  port: 3000
});

webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
  var id = Math.random();
  clients[id] = ws;



  console.log(`Connection extablished ${id}`);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(`Server got a message ${message}`);

    for (var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*border: 1px solid purple;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 81%;
  height: 42%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.chat {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#chatList {
  background-color: olivedrab;
  float: left;
  height: 95%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.subscribe {
  background-color: olivedrab;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 68%;
  height: 90%;
  border: solid 1px cornflowerblue;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 7px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 42%;
}

.status {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message {
  padding: 20px;
}

#statusElem {
  padding: 20px;
}

#login {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <title>WebSocket</title>
</head>

<body>



  <div id="chat" class="chat">
    <div id="chatList">
      <li><a href="#">chat 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">chat 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">chat 3</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="subscribe" class="subscribe"></div>

    <form name="publish">
      <input type="text" name="message" class="input">
      <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="button" id="start">
    </form>

    <div id="status" class="status"></div>

  </div>

  <div><input id="login" type="text" style="background-color: cornflowerblue" /></div>
  <button id="join">Join chat</button>

  <script src="./js/browser.js"></script>
</body>
```

Commented code is my trials to reach the expected result. Please, don't use jQuery, special tools for chat development (like Expres). It is a must for me to know the basics, so I would be grateful if you help me.